# Asp Mvc one way model property, i.e. from client only

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there an attribute or something similar in Asp MVC to indicate that a property should only come from the client, i.e. it shouldn't be roundtripped.

So

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MyProp)
```

I set this somehow on the client together with some other properties, it goes the server, server has a model error so sends it all back. I don't want this one property to be roundtripped.

The best I can think of is to do this

```
<input type="hidden" name=MyPropOneWay />
```

Then I manually insert it at the controller end into the property

(Addition)
It's not to avoid model errors, it's because there are a few ways of submitting the form, this is a shortcut method. In no circumstance do I want this value to be roundtripped as otherwise it will look like it's been set when it hasn't, however I do want everything else to be roundtripped

Thanks

Comment: there will be model error only when you use some model validations on a field if you will not use any data annotations on a field then it will not create any model error.

Comment: Details added, it's not to avoid model errors

Comment: You can use `ModelState[your Property].Errors.Clear();` to clear the errors for a property

Comment: It might be that there aren't any model errors but I still don't want this value roundtripped

Comment: @MemetOlsen, Hadn't seen the edit :). But if the property is reset in the controller, then its still required anyway (otherwise the value will be taken from `ModelState`, not the property value).

Comment: I don't want it to be taken from the controller, or the ModelState. I don't want it to come from the server side at all, hence the term oneway

Comment: Then don't make it a property of your model.

Comment: I still need it to come back, which I can do by looking in Request.Params. It might be thats what you have to do

Comment: Could you change your POST controller method to accept  `FormCollection` instead of the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the value rendered from the server (either initially or after a roundtrip), use:

```
<input type="hidden" name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.MyProp)" />
```

This will render an `input hidden` element without a value, but it will still have the correct name to automatically bind to your model on form submission. Which effectively makes it "one way".

(The `NameFor` helper was added in MVC4)

Comment: Sounds ideal, thanks for that :-) (sorry for the delay, was on a support call)